# Quantile Regression - Linear Loss Minimization

Tags: calculus, statistics, regression

I'm currently reading *Quantile Regression* by Roger Koenker, and for some reason, I'm having a lot of trouble deriving one of his equations (sect. 1.3, p. 5-6).

He goes on to demonstrate that $\hat{x}$ minimizing a linear loss corresponds to the $τ$th quartile of the distribution, when the loss is defined by
$$
\rho_\tau(u) = (\tau - 1)\min(0,u) + \tau \max(0,u).
$$

To do so, he first writes down the expected loss using the CDF $F$ of the distribution:
$$
E[\rho_\tau(X-\hat x)] = (\tau -1)\int_{-\infty}^{\hat x}(x-\hat x)\,dF(x) + \tau \int_{\hat x}^\infty (x-\hat x)\,dF(x), \tag 1
$$
where $X$ is a random variable, which he then differentiates by $\hat x$ to obtain
$$
(1-\tau)\int_{-\infty}^{\hat x} dF(x) - τ\int_{\hat x}^\infty dF(x) \tag 2
$$
Now I'm a bit rusty with calculus, and I couldn't find how to go from (1) to (2). I tried to integrate by parts and to apply the fundamental theorem, but I couldn't obtained the result (2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This results from applying [Leibniz's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{d\hat x} E_{ϱ_τ}(X-\hat x) &=& (τ -1)\frac{d}{d\hat x}\int_{-∞}^{\hat x}(x-\hat x)\,dF(x)+τ\frac{d}{d\hat x}\int_{\hat x}^{∞}(x-\hat x)\,dF(x) \\
&=& (τ -1)\left((x - \hat x)|_{\hat x} + \int_{-∞}^{\hat x} \frac{d}{d\hat x}(x-\hat x)\,dF(x)\right)+τ\left((x - \hat x)|_{\hat x} + \int_{\hat x}^{∞}\frac{d}{d\hat x}(x-\hat x)\,dF(x)\right) \\
&=& (τ -1)\left(0 + \int_{-∞}^{\hat x} (-1)\,dF(x)\right)+τ\left(0 + \int_{\hat x}^{∞}(-1)\,dF(x)\right) \\
&=& (1 - \tau)\int_{-∞}^{\hat x} \,dF(x)-τ\int_{\hat x}^{∞}\,dF(x) \\
\end{eqnarray*}